# Do I need a transit visa to visit Manila from India?

Tags: visa

I was checking flights from Delhi to Manila, and found there has to be a stop in either Hong Kong or Kuala Lumpur.

I am not interested to enter either of these places during the stopover. I will wait and stay in the airport only.

So, do I still need a transit visa?

Comment: Can you confirm you are an Indian citizen please.

Comment: Yes I am. Is this a reason of downvote, that I missed to mention it in question?

Comment: No, the reason for the downvote is that the answer is trivially google-able.

Comment: You can google anything, still posting it on SE depends on few other important things. Tried to clarify by a comment on your answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the belongs on Travel.SE

Comment: Travel.SE question?

Answer (score 1):

Hong Kong: https://www.immd.gov.hk/eng/services/visas/pre-arrival_registration_for_indian_nationals.html says

> Pre-arrival registration is not required for Indian nationals in direct transit by air and not leaving the airport transit area.

China: https://www.travelchinaguide.com/embassy/visa/transit.htm says

> For foreigners who hold tickets to a third country and have booked seats on international airlines, ships, trains transiting through China, if the stay is less than 24 hours, they can enjoy the 24-hour visa-free transit. In case they want to leave the specified transit zone, they can ask for a temporary stay permit at the immigration counter. The 24-hour direct transit facility benefits almost all country citizens and is available in most China ports

Malaysia: http://www.kln.gov.my/web/ind_chennai/faqs says

> PASSENGER WHO INTENDED NOT TO LEAVE THE AIRPORT
>
> If you are already check in for the next flight and do not plan to leave the airport terminal (i.e. you just want to wait for the next flight in the terminal building), Malaysian visa is not required.

I don't know where MY is, so I can't tell if you need a transit visa or not.

Note: All of those were found by typing `<country> transit visa` in google.  Why didn't you do that?

Comment: SG = Singaore, MY = Malaysia, KL=Kuala Lumpur, HK=Hong Kong, CN=China

Comment: @paul Err - KL is in Malaysia.

Comment: I didnt try the way you suggested. I was typing `Transit Visa from Del-MNL`. Maybe I was searching wrong string in google. Also I was getting mixed results some say Yes, some No. Your answer is pretty detailed with source link

Comment: I didnt write it is not there. I am just sharing Kuala Lumpur in short is KL.

Comment: @paul Very few countries are going to care where you are flying from or where you are flying to in order to decide whether you need a transit visa.  The important point is where you are in transit.

Comment: Didnt know that, it will be first out of country flight, needed a trustworthy source. I trust SE. There will be more flights after that I will be more educated on this, not good as you, but some.